# How to add a line inside a D3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have developed a D3 chart using D3 version 3. In there I need to add a separator line in the chart to separate columns. The chart represents months and that line is used to separate the months of two years. Is there a possible way to add this kind of a line into a chart. Always the separator position is not fixed, it may be here and there depending on where January is marked in the chart. The following picture shows an expected behavior. And sample code is also given, Can someone give a solution for this problem

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yasirunilan/921fsugh/4/

[image]

```
const sample = [{
        month: 'Sep',
        value: 78.9,
        color: '#000000',
        date: '30/09/17'
    },
    {
        month: 'Oct',
        value: 75.1,
        color: '#00a2ee',
        date: '31/10/17'
    },
    {
        month: 'Nov',
        value: 68.0,
        color: '#fbcb39',
        date: '30/11/17'
    },
    {
        month: 'Dec',
        value: 67.0,
        color: '#007bc8',
        date: '31/12/17'
    },
    {
        month: 'Jan',
        value: 65.6,
        color: '#65cedb',
        date: '31/01/18'
    },
    {
        month: 'Feb',
        value: 65.1,
        color: '#ff6e52',
        date: '28/02/18'
    },
    {
        month: 'Mar',
        value: 61.9,
        color: '#f9de3f',
        date: '31/03/18'
    },
    {
        month: 'Apr',
        value: 60.4,
        color: '#5d2f8e',
        date: '30/04/18'
    },
    {
        month: 'May',
        value: 59.6,
        color: '#008fc9',
        date: '31/05/18'
    },
    {
        month: 'Jun',
        value: 59.6,
        color: '#507dca',
        date: '30/06/18'
    },
    {
        month: 'Jul',
        value: 80.6,
        color: '#507dca',
        date: '31/07/18'
    },
    {
        month: 'Aug',
        value: 45.6,
        color: '#507dca',
        date: '31/08/18'
    },
    {
        month: 'Sep ',
        value: 78.6,
        color: '#507dca',
        date: '30/09/18'
    }
];

const svg = d3.select('svg');
const svgContainer = d3.select('#container');

const margin = 80;
const width = 1000 - 2 * margin;
const height = 600 - 2 * margin;

const chart = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);

const xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.4)
    .domain(sample.map((s) => s.month))

const yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 100]);

// vertical grid lines
// const makeXLines = () => d3.axisBottom()
//   .scale(xScale)

const makeYLines = () => d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")


chart.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").tickSize(1));

chart.append('g')
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left").tickFormat(d3.format("d")).tickSize(1));

// vertical grid lines
// chart.append('g')
//   .attr('class', 'grid')
//   .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
//   .call(makeXLines()
//     .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
//     .tickFormat('')
//   )

chart.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'grid')
    .call(makeYLines()
        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat('')
    )

const barGroups = chart.selectAll()
    .data(sample)
    .enter()
    .append('g')

barGroups
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', (g) => xScale(g.month))
    .attr('y', (g) => yScale(g.value))
    .attr('height', (g) => height - yScale(g.value))
    .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
    .on('mouseenter', function(actual, i) {
        d3.selectAll('.value')
            .attr('opacity', 0)

        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(300)
            .attr('opacity', 0.6)
            .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.month) - 5)
            .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand() + 10)

        const y = yScale(actual.value)

        line = chart.append('line')
            .attr('id', 'limit')
            .attr('x1', 0)
            .attr('y1', y)
            .attr('x2', width)
            .attr('y2', y)

        barGroups.append('text')
            .attr('class', 'divergence')
            .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.month) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
            .attr('y', (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
            .attr('fill', 'white')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .text((a, idx) => {
                const divergence = (a.value - actual.value).toFixed(1)

                let text = ''
                if (divergence > 0) text += '+'
                text += `${divergence}%`

                return idx !== i ? text : '';
            })

    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        d3.selectAll('.value')
            .attr('opacity', 1)

        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(300)
            .attr('opacity', 1)
            .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.month))
            .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())

        chart.selectAll('#limit').remove()
        chart.selectAll('.divergence').remove()
    })

barGroups
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'value')
    .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.month) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr('y', (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text((a) => `${a.value}%`)

svg
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .attr('x', -(height / 2) - margin)
    .attr('y', margin / 2.4)
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text('Love meter (%)')

svg.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
    .attr('y', height + margin * 1.7)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text('Months')

svg.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'title')
    .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
    .attr('y', 40)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text('Most loved programming languages in 2018')

svg.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'source')
    .attr('x', width - margin / 2)
    .attr('y', height + margin * 1.7)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
    .text('Source: Stack Overflow, 2018')
```

Comment: Is this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752764/how-to-add-a-separator-in-d3-bar-chart a duplicate of this ticket? Just curious to know.

Comment: Quite similar, the solutions given in that question is not valid for D3v3 that's why I raised a separate question with D3 V3 code.

Comment: Okay.. Got it!.

Comment: @DavidR but it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53316144/9938317

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a separator in D3 bar chart D3V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316144/how-to-add-a-separator-in-d3-bar-chart-d3v3)

Comment: @rioV8 Great eyes! Nice catch! :-)

Comment: @DavidR: I just answered that question